# C параметры командной строки

Tags: c, c++

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc <= 1){
        cout << "Not enough args.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    for(i = 2; i <= argc; i++){
        while(argv[i][j]){
            cout << argv[i][j];
            j++;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Что здесь не так?

Comment: счёт в массиве начинается с "0"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот здесь i должно быть 0, т.к. ка правильно заметил ProkletyiPirat первый элемент массива 0, то i=2 будет выводить параметры, начиная с 3-го

```
for(i = 2; i <= argc; i++){
    while(argv[i][j]){
        cout << argv[i][j];
        j++;
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

правильно

```
for(i = 0; i <= argc; i++){
    while(argv[i][j]){
        cout << argv[i][j];
        j++;
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: @CyberCoder, так тоже неправильно (поскольку argv[argc] == NULL (!!!), то получите Segmentation Fault), да и `j` не мешает обнулять перед `while()`.

Правильно:

    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++){
      j = 0;
      while (argv[i][j]){
        cout << argv[i][j];
        j++;
      }
      cout << "\n";
    }

а еще проще:

    for (i = 0; argv[i]; i++)
      cout << argv[i] << '\n';

Если имя программы (argv[0]) печатать не надо, то соответственно

    for (i = 1; argv[i]; i++) ...

Comment: согласен, не особо всматривался в код, увидел неправильный начальный индекс и скопировал код, изменив начальное значение переменной.